# SELECT ALL * FROM DeviceIDs HAVING UserID=:id in php only returns one instance?

Tags: php, mysql, web, pdo

In php, I am trying to access ALL the DeviceIDs matching their user ID. It only returns one of them, the first one in the MySQL table.

This is my code. How do I fix this.

```
            if (!$query = $db->prepare('SELECT ALL * FROM DeviceIDs HAVING UserID=:id')) {
            exit('{"result": "something went wrong preparing the query"}');
        }

        if (!$query->execute(array(':id' => $secondData["id"]))) {
            exit('{"result": "something went wrong executing query"}');
        }

        $thirdData = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo '' . json_encode($thirdData);
```

Comment: @Bent783 what kind of framework do you use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must iterate with a loop the return of fetch method like:

```
 while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
     $thirdData[] = $row;
 }
 print_r($thirData);
```